# after loading html file into another html file, jquery show hide not working in chrome but it is working in firefox

Tags: jquery, html

After loading html file into another html file, jquery show hide not working in chrome but it is working in firefox.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#includedContent").load("dashboard-body.html");
    $("#includefolder").load("folder-setup.html");
    $("#foldercont").click(function(){
    $("#includedContent").hide();
    $("#includefolder").show();
    });
         
    $("#dashboard").click(function(){
    $("#includefolder").hide();
    $("#includedContent").show();
    });
    });
</script>
```

now follows a code block for Jquery hide and show:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#folderclick').click(function(){
    $('#displayform').show();
    $('#displayview').hide();
    $('#tabcontent').hide();    

    }); 
    $('#dissubmit').click(function(){
    $('#displayform').hide();
    $('#tabcontent').show();    
    }); 
    
    $('#viewfolder').click(function(){
    $('#displayview').show();
    $('#displayform').hide();
    $('#tabcontent').hide();    
    }); 
    $('#viewsubmit').click(function(){
    $('#displayview').hide();
    $('#editdis').show();
    });     
    $('#editsub').click(function(){
    $('#editdis').hide();   
    }); 
    $('#deleteclick').click(function(){
    $('#disalert').show();
    }); 
    });
```

Comment: I think you need to describe in more detail what you mean by _"show hide not working"_ - in what way is it not working? Can you edit your post to clarify that? Also, have you tried using the Javascript debugger in the two browsers? I'd expect that to give you quite a lot more useful information, that might help you to solve the problem yourself, or, if not, help others here to answer it for you.

Comment: you need to follow event delegation.